# Php codes for downloading Excel file is not working

Tags: php, excel, downloading-website-files

I can't download excel file, it downloads the file but it doesn't have a contents and its size is 0kb. This is my html code.

```
<h5 style="color: red;">
    <a href="2.php?file=files/Battle_Entry_form.xls" class="links">
        Click here to download A Registration form
    </a>
</h5> <br />
```

2.php (this is my php codes for downloading excel file)

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['file'])){
    $filename = $_GET['file'];

    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');

    readfile("http://www.caledtech.com/batllewebsite/".$filename);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Is there something missing in my codes?

Comment: Let's see.... not doing anything to check that the specified file actually exists, not checking that some unscrupulous user is trying to download a passwords file, what more wrong do you need telling about?

Comment: Perhaps the site you're grabbing the file from dislikes your activities and has taken some actions. In any case, do you understand what your code does? You're omitting some fairly obvious trouble-shooting steps.

Comment: @asker, you should use 'readfile' from local server

Comment: I don't understand the codes, I'm modifying the website from the former developer of this. I found out that the download function is just downloading the file without any contents inside it. The file size is only 0kb once being downloaded. The excel file is already in the website, I just need to fix the codes for downloading the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP manual of [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) said:

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.

I think you should use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead of readfile:

```
echo file_get_contents("http://www.caledtech.com/batllewebsite/".$filename);
```

And I recommend to you to use [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) for the filename:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
```

Comment: I tried your codes but it's also the same, the file size being downloaded is still 0kb. Can you give me a sample php codes for downloading excel file? I really need it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you checked you haven't PHP errors in your logs ? Maybe you can't get a external file with your PHP configuration. Moreover, your file doesn't exist : http://www.caledtech.com/batllewebsite/files/Battle_Entry_form.xls.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using PHPExcel

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

[How to use PHPExcel](https://arjunphp.com/how-to-use-phpexcel-with-codeigniter/)

If the content of the Excel file contains gibberish, try adding `ob_clean();` or `ob_end_clean();` right before saving at this line: `$objWriter->save();`